# Unmount children not triggering componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### The problem

The `React.unmountComponentAtNode` within `unmountInput` of **InputsList.jsx** isn't triggering the `componentWillUnmount` within **Input.jsx**.

#### The code

This is the entire code of **InputsList.jsx**:

```
//...
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    keyRefs: []
  };
},
handleKeyRefs: function () {
  var index = 0;

  this.props.inputs.keys.forEach(function () {
    this.state.keyRefs.push('key-' + index++);
  }.bind(this));
},
componentWillMount: function () {
  this.handleKeyRefs();
},
render: function () {
  return (
    <section className="inputs">
      <ul>
        {this.props.inputs.keys.map(this.renderInput)}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
},
renderInput: function (key, index) {
  return <Input representation={key.representation} code={key.code} ref={this.state.keyRefs[index]} key={index} />;
},
componentDidMount: function () {
  var inputs  = this.props.inputs.keys
      , index = 0;

  $(window).on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === inputs[0].code) {
      inputs.shift();

      this.unmountInput(index++);
    };
  }.bind(this));
},
unmountInput: function (index) {
  return React.unmountComponentAtNode(React.findDOMNode(this.refs['key-' + index]));
}
//...
```

**Input.jsx**:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    representation: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <li className="input">{this.props.representation}</li>
    );
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    console.log('unmounted!');
  }
});

module.exports = Input;
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `React.unmountComponentAtNode(node)` unless you previously did `React.render(stuff, node)`.

If you want to change the children of your component, you need to change your data (props/state) so that render gives the desired output.

Because you use this.props.inputs, your options are:

- have the component using InputsList give an updated input prop

  - you probably want this
- store enough data in state to allow `this.props.input.keys.filter(someCondition).map(this.renderInput)`

Read [Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) (maybe multiple times, I've read it at least 5).

Comment: It's funny, but only after reading your answer I understood the different between rendering a component and handling the state object. Thanks. (I was trying to unmount a child component that was created by the state of his parent instead of just removing the child from the state)